# Centralised property file management

Tags: mule

All,

I am looking for a centralised properties management solution, for eg: I have a flow/application in Mule. I have multiple property files for different environments. Which works great, like any other application.

The properties configured in these files are pretty much username, passwords, target endpoints etc. BUT I don't want to expose them in these simple files. Instead I am looking for a centralised solution where I can configure my properties as keys and just use the keys in my application.

Something like this

database-user=${central-properties-key.database.user}

instead of

database-user=dbuser1

I know, I can use something like [Zuul](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-meets-zuul-centralized-properties-management-part-1/) here. But there are no hosted solution for Zuul, as far as I have searched. (I don't like to host and manage anything on premise ;) )

Thoughts ? Any other best approach in mind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Zuul and Mule before.  Its lot more easier than handling properties file manually. Advantages are:
1) UI based key value pair definition
2) Separation of Environments (like a Zuul instance having DEV,TEST & UAT configurations and separate instance for PROD configurations)
3) Mule Supports Zuul integration for Properties
4) Data in Zuul can be encrypted (it maintains data in database internally)
5) User access control on configuration data can be done

A disadvantage in Zuul or in using Property/Secure property placeholder is that we cannot dynamically access values - Mule forces a redeployment of app.  To overcome this, we built wrapper APIs which fetch properties from Zuul (based on environment) at runtime.  These were not out of the box in Mule/Zuul but its mostly required to avoid restarts.

Thanks,

Ananth

Comment: Thanks Ananth, your point on redeployment is a very good point. Certainly  we hate redeployment's. For that matter, mule redeploys the application even if you update the property using cloudhub console. Wrapper API is interesting as well, I will jump on and give it a try. Looks like Zuul is the best possible solution for the moment, Cant find any other alternate option really.

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple files in the repo e.g. dev.properties, qa.properties, and stage.properties. These would remain with the project. Then prod.properties would stay with me on my personal machine.

I would then add this to the mule config:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${env}.properties"/>
```

In mule-app.properties I would add this:

```
env=dev
```

If someone tampers with a database or endpoint on dev,qa,stage I'm not as concerned as I would be if they harmed production. For production, I would script the operation of copying the prod.properties into the project, setting env=prod and then doing a Maven clean package just before the deployment was ready to be dropped in the production server's app directory.

What do you think? If you agree, let me know and give me a vote on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are already using what David mentions. I also see the ZUUL blogpost is for an older version of mule.

As I understand from your explanation though you request for the centralized mechanism for storing the properties the need for it is the security and the below answers accordingly.

The Mule now has a better feature like the following

- Secure properties : When we use this the Anypoint cloud the mentioned properties will be Asterisked e.g. **** . The Properties in the property file need not be given or kept empty and while deploying the Admin provides the details and it will also be masked
- Property placeholder encryption : When used the Properties in the property file will be encrypted

Please go through the below links for more information.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-credentials-vault

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/installing-anypoint-enterprise-security

For this you need to install the Mule security module from the bleow site to your Anypoint studio(which is like eclipse )

http://security-update-site.s3.amazonaws.com/

Install the security module form there.

There are other features that Mule provides as part of enterprise solution for security .

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I have already gone through all those links. mule-credentials-vault is promising, but my requirement is slightly different. I don't want mule developer to know any of the values, meaning I don't want the mule developers to know any usernames or passwords. The whole username and password will be managed by someother team. Mule guys will know only the keys for username and passwords. Get the idea ? Any solution/ thoughts coming into your mind ? That way Zuul is very close, only thing is I need to host Zuul somewhere myself.

Comment: I am not restricting with solutions with Zuul alone, I am happy to look at any other best practices as well. For eg: There is one practice, where infra guys can set these properties as system properties, that way only the user which runs mule can read those system properties. I am basically exploring what is the best way to achieve my requirement. :)

Comment: IS this on Premise or on cloud. Who does the deployment. If deployment is done by Infra guys then Masking solution is one option you can think of which I mentioned in the answer. Would that work . Only the person who deploys is can see the password and once the first deployment is made  for any one who sees the properties it will be shown as ***. Also Mule has RBAC which can help is restricting the access as well.

Answer (score 0):

For environment specific passwords, we usually add a last file in context:property-placeholder -

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" 
    location="project-common.properties,env/project-${env_name}.properties,file:///var/mule/properties/project.properties"/>
```

Offcourse, you can name properties whatever way you want. All passwords then goes to file:///var/mule/properties/project.properties on server with read permission to mule user only.

Comment: @Downvoter, downvoting is fine but it should be accompanied with a comment for why downvote? The questions also asked about other best approaches. All three answers on here gives different approaches for same situation. What you think is best, may not be best for others so consider answers judiciously and discuss on them with people. Hope you find your "Best" answer soon!